# why items are not loading in blog.vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am loading template from blog.vue in app.js, but with this it displays only header row of table not table rows as ajax call is not made.

If i comment **require('./bootstrap');**, it does not display table header, ajax is called but no data is displayed in table rows.

**1. blog.vue file**

```
<template>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-borderless">
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="item in items">
      <td>@{{ item.title }}</td>
      <td>@{{ item.description }}</td>

    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component ready.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**2. app.js file**

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('list-blog', require('./components/blog.vue'));

new Vue({
  el :'#manage-vue',
  data :{
    items: [],
    newItem : {'title':'','description':''},
    fillItem : {'title':'','description':'','id':''}
  },

  ready: function() {
    this.getVueItems();
  },
  methods: {
    getVueItems: function() {
      this.$http.get('/vueitems?page='+page).then((response) => {
        this.$set('items', response.data.data.data);
        this.$set('pagination', response.data.pagination);
      });
    },
  }
});
```

**3. bootstrap.js**

```
window._ = require('lodash');

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');


window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);

    next();
});
```

Can you please tell me where am i wrong in this ? i am using laravel-elixir here.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be only response.data.data

```
// this.$set('items', response.data.data.data);
// to
this.$set('items', response.data.data);
```

You could even simplify this

```
this.$http.get('/vueitems?page='+page).then((response) => {
    this.items = response.data.data;
    this.pagination = response.data.pagination;
}.bind(this)); // important bind(this)
```

It seems like you are returning a paginated object. Therefore the third data is false - isn't it?
Also you would usually pass the items to the component as property. Simply define the prop at your blog.vue

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['items'],
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component ready.')
    }
}
</script>
```

And then pass it whereever you use it

```
<list-blog :items="items"></list-blog>
```

I highly recommend to use Chrome and the Vue devtools https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools - these will help you to follow and undestand the data bindings

Another smaller thing is that you shouldn't bind the pagination object AND the items seperatly. The pagination object contains the items. If you don't want o use "pagination.data" in your templates simply use a computed property instead of creating two sources of truth.

Comment: but why vue is not making api call? and i have used pagination but for here i have omitted that, so i guess there is no problem with ajax call.

Comment: try to use "created" instead of ready, please also tell us which vue js version you are working with

Comment: i have tried "created" instead of ready but did not work for me. And i have tried with vue js 1.0.26 and 2.1.6, but did not work.

Comment: You do not get any console errors? Did you require vue-resource? In your question you said "ajax is called, but no data is displayed" - why is ajax now not called anymore?

Comment: if i comment require('./bootstrap'); then ajax is called though data is not displaying. if i dont comment nothing is happening.

Comment: well it highly depends on the content of yor bootstrap.js file then. Please add it.

Comment: looks fine - is there any output after running gulp?